# Python - Convert categorical variables with missing values into one-hot encoded variables - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset with categorical variables. These categorical variables have data that is missing. From my understanding I want to get the most frequent categorical value to impute the NaNs.

From what I understand Scikit learn has the Onehot encoder, but it ends up removing the column labels. We also have to encode the variables into number first before onehot encoding.

I also saw that pandas had a get_dummies function to give me the dummy variables and it also created a variable for the NaNs. The issue is imputing the values.

I created this:

```
def produce_dummies(X, label):#gives us the mode for the categorical variable
    dummies = pd.get_dummies(X[label], dummy_na = True)
    mode_label = dummies.sum().sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=False).head(1).index[0]
    dummies[mode_label] += dummies[None]
    del dummies[None]
    X = pd.concat([X, dummies], axis=1)#make the dummies and concat with original data
    X.drop(label, inplace=True, axis=1)#drop the original columns
    return X
```

Is there a more efficient way to turn categorical variables with missing values into one-hot encoded variables?

edit:
Data.csv:

```
country,age,gender,salary
Poland,,Female,119459
Colombia,73,Male,109999
China,,Male,135392
Indonesia,91,Male,49886
Czech Republic,53,Male,103178
Canada,136,Female,131605
Indonesia,,Male,146128
China,,Female,119298
China,116,Female,123175
Vietnam,114,Male,138617
Palestinian Territory,32,Male,
Pakistan,45,Female,66317
China,140,Female,71870
Indonesia,,Female,
Poland,61,Male,69626
Mexico,149,Male,75329
Indonesia,53,Male,27189
Macedonia,36,Male,104105
Argentina,129,Female,
China,71,Male,74527
Philippines,70,Female,75104
China,133,Male,90145
South Korea,27,Male,92813
Portugal,97,Male,31438
Russia,63,Male,94148
Poland,62,Female,114636
Portugal,,Female,67986
Cuba,65,Female,92651
Indonesia,38,Female,107158
China,23,Female,61712
Saudi Arabia,,Male,58346
Argentina,66,Female,65748
Sweden,60,Male,84878
China,108,Male,73105
Russia,98,Male,
China,26,Female,63551
Brazil,75,Male,
Somalia,141,Female,95899
Thailand,34,Female,115984
China,111,Male,145321
China,29,Male,47681
Argentina,126,Female,75877
Russia,105,Female,90894
Indonesia,133,Male,86528
Philippines,22,Female,87861
Russia,28,Female,139846
Greece,56,Female,68124
Philippines,104,Female,113103
Belarus,101,Male,31092
Equatorial Guinea,141,Male,102130
Czech Republic,136,Female,68754
Indonesia,64,Male,36757
Costa Rica,41,Female,123774
France,83,Male,117321
Portugal,125,Male,20817
Italy,119,Male,134512
Sweden,78,Male,97482
China,146,Female,
China,89,Male,100798
France,36,Male,99792
,63,Female,90067
China,150,Male,
Liberia,67,Female,91082
Japan,,Male,145330
,,Female,96553
```

## Use method above

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')#
X = data.iloc[:,0:3]#variables
y = data.iloc[:,3]#variables
#use the method above
X = produce_dummies(X, 'country')
```

Comment: Can you add soem data sample, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @jezrael added example

Comment: So what do you want to do? First fill the missing values with the most frequent value and then one-hot encode them>

Comment: @VivekKumar yes

Comment: To those who vote to close, can you give me a reason why? Is this the correct method to use? If so then answer it as such.